# Can't clear a cache of Joomla module

Tags: joomla-3.x, module, joomla-api, cache

I created some Joomla module for my client and he installed it in his backend. After a while I made some edits in the module and my client reinstalled it but my edits don't apply on his website (though they successfully apply on my website). On the System tab of his website the Progressive caching is enabled. I turned caching off in the Advanced tab of the module, select the module in the Manage tab and refreshed its cache and also cleared all the cache in the System tab of client's backend but nothing resolved the problem. What did I miss? How to clear the cache of my module completely and apply my edits?

Joomla 3.4.5

**UPDATED:** My module does some stuff depending on the current url of a page:

```
$parts = explode(JURI::base(), JURI::getInstance()->toString());
$currentUrl = $parts[1];
echo $currentUrl;
```

and I found out when I pass to another page the code echoes the url of previous page but not the current one. It seems like some cache of urls. How can I clear it?

Comment: Does his hosting use their own cache? I only ask cause Siteground who I am hosted with use extremely aggressive caching which I sometimes forget to flush

Comment: It would be done via your hosting control panel

Comment: Unfortunately, flushing the hosting cache didn't help. But I found out more info. See updated question

Comment: In the Joomla backend, did you try clearing the expired cache?

Comment: Yes, I did but it also didn't help. Regarding the url of page I meant adding or removing some key. For example if I'm on page with url `/etc` and click some link in module with key `?currency=usd` I pass to page with url `/etc?currency=usd` (that's ok) but the code of my module still echoes `/etc` as current url

Comment: Ahh ok. I believe it's due to `$parts[1]`. The URL is being exploded into an array and only a specific section is being returned, not all of it

Comment: No, it's not due to `$parts[1]` for as I said it works perfectly in my website (where caching is disabled) and it works on client's website if I turn caching off. But caching must be enabled. And it doesn't work even if I switch caching from progressive to conservative

Comment: @Lodder, could you write in answer how to clear the cache of module every time when outputing with `JCache` and `$cache->remove()` like [joomla.stackexchange.com](http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/5133/using-jcache-to-clear-a-specific-plugins-cached-data) ?

Comment: Oh, even when I enable cache on my website my module still works fine. It turns out that it's something with cache on client's website

Comment: Check is htaccess settings and if your client has another cache extension installed. (I had such issues with a cache extension, even updates on articles didn't showed up.) 

For testing, did you deactivated the cache plugin?

Comment: If you have cleared server cache could it then be browser cache?  Have you cleared that too?

Comment: The question has three years and is no longer actual

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps your module has an override in the template used by the website. You can verify this in the template configuration page of the back-office. If that's the case, just delete the /templates/[template name]/html/[mod_your_template] folder, and Joomla will use your original module files.

Comment: Thank you for contributing! With some luck, stckvrw will still have a way to verify if this is a working solution.  Regardless, other researchers may benefit from your advice.  Please continue to post answers when you have valuable insights to share.